# Copy every field of a class instance to another class instance to keep the data binding

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a class instance of my class `Poste` (let's call it `A`) that has a DataBinding with my interface.

What I want to do is to copy every single property of another `Poste` class instance (I'll call it `B`) without losing the data binding of `A` with my interface.

What I naively first did :

```cs
//A already created
Poste B = new Poste();
A = B;
```

Of course it didn't worked because it passed the references.

After that I heard about `shallow copy` and `deep copy` so I tried to do a deep copy of my `B` class instance to `A`.
(used deep copy class on internet, it's working)

```cs
A = ObjectExtensions.Copy(B); //making a deep copy of B into A
```

I thought it would copy `B` on the same `A` instance but still the data binding was not working anymore because `INotifyPropertyChanged` was not triggered.

So is there any simple way to copy every single field and property of a class 
without changing the current instance and losing the data binding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is to copy every single property of another `Poste` class instance (I'll call it `B`) without losing the data binding of `A` with my interface.

Then you should set every property of the existing instance of `A`. You may do this using reflection:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = A.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if (property.CanWrite)
        property.SetValue(A, property.GetValue(B));
}
```

Comment: if I have other class instances in that class, will it also copy them without removing the data binding instance ?

Comment: It will replace the reference to the nested object without affecting the data binding to the nested property.